# Finding BigO - One while-loop nested with two for-loops

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, big-o

Can someone tell me the BigO of the following:

```
public void doFoo(int n) {
    int pass = 1;
    while (pass <= n) {
        for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
            for (int count = 1; count < 10; count++) {
                if (arr1[pass] == arr2[index]) {
                    arr1[pass]++;
                }
            }
        }
        pass = pass + 1;
    }
}
```

I've come to the conclusion O(n2), but I would like some clarification on whether it is correct. Help appreciated.

Comment: You have 2 *nested* loops dependent on the size of n and a single constant loop. This is O(n^2)

Comment: The outer loop is just a different way of writing a for-loop. It's probably there just as an attempt on the part of your educator to confound the student who is solving assignments by rote memorization.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Glad to see i'm on the right track. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `0(n^2)` ..  Here is the logic :

```
 while (pass <= n) {                     // executes n times
        for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {      // executes n times
            for (int count = 1; count < 10; count++) { // always executes 9 times.. irrespective of "n". So. it doesn't matter.
                if (arr1[pass] == arr2[index]) {
                    arr1[pass]++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Technically, the first loop goes from `1` to `n`. It actually loops `n` times.

Comment: Yes, as always it is easiest to check for the edge case: `n == 1` -> loop executes once.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - didn't see it properly.. edited it now :P (not that it makes any difference:P)

Comment: Yeah, the analysis is exactly the same: `arr1[pass]` gets incremented `n * n * 10` times = `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - actually `n * n* 9` times :P

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very well explained. Have a nice weekend. :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - `n==1` is edge case?

Comment: `n==0` -> loop doesn't execute at all, `n==1` -> it executes once. That's why I'd call it an edge case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik :-) n==1 was always the first step in proving something by Mathematical induction :P

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm getting at: maybe I should have said "base case".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Oh.. okies :)